# PHP conditions and loops are breaking html formatting

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to convert my html template into a php script that simply takes returned database values and uses comparisons on certain values to place the correct content in the placeholders.

The data is being returned properly and is showing on the page but my html formatting is breaking.

This should output a very simple format of a container row, 2 half-width columns each of which with its own internal div like this:

```
<div class="row middle">
    <div class="col-lg-6 leftFifty">
        <div class="leftContent" style="background-color: white; height: 100%; ">       
        Content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 rightFifty">
      <div class="rightContent" style="background-color: white; height: 100%; ">
      Content
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I add in the PHP conditions it breaks the format completely including anything included after this section

```
<div class="row middle">
    <?php foreach($panelResult as $PR): ?>
    <div class="col-lg-6 leftFifty">
        <?php if($PR['panel_type_id'] == 2){ ?>
        <div class="leftContent" style="background-color: white; height: 100%; ">       
        <?php echo $PR['content']?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 rightFifty">
        <?php } elseif($PR['panel_type_id'] == 3){?>
      <div class="rightContent" style="background-color: white; height: 100%; ">
        <?php  echo $PR['content'] ?>
      </div>
     <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

<!--This div is not showing-->
<div class="row bottom">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="marquee"><h2>This is a test</h2></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For this page type, row-middle should exist, and both the leftFifty/leftContent class as well as the rightFifty and rightContent class should all exist.

The only reason I'm using the If statement is to make sure that the panel_type_id ==2 content fills the left div, and same for the right div if it equals 3.

How can I restructure this to retain the html formatting?

Comment: `endforeach` needs a semi colon after it `endforeach;`

Comment: Your if blocks aren't properly wrapped around the HTML.  You're going to have `.leftFifty` regardless but you close it within the  if block.   The indentation  should have been your first clue.

Comment: _For this page type_ What page type. We are not clairvoyant! I assume you mean `panel_type` when you say page type, but your IF's are checking 2 different `page_types` ... I mean `panel_types`

Comment: @RiggsFolly when I say this page type, I mean this template. It's loading a template that contains the two half-width panels. The verbiage in my statements is correct, but the page type refers to the whole page that contains these panels. panel_type is only referring to the data I get back being either 2 or 3

Comment: @Devon even changing that back as it is now above, I'm getting the two divs on top of each other rather than beside each other

Comment: @TomN. you still didn't fix it.  Look at where your first if block starts and finishes.  It starts below the .leftFifty div open and closes after it.

Comment: Oh shoot @Devon, I just realized I moved the second one without moving the first one back. I think that got it, thank you!